# How to get number of items in list from Python Function

Tags: python, list

My function returns a list but fails to return the length of the list.

When I return the list itself (commented in the code below) it is successful but on attempting to return the length of the list it fails yet this usually works with other lists that I work with??!!

I tried using a count variable that I incremented by 1 every time a sub-list was added to the list but on attempting to print the count, the error below still occurred. You can see it commented out in the code as well.

```
def count_combinations(number, integers_available, integers):

    combination_set = []
    # count = 0

    if sum(integers) == number:
        combination_set.append(integers)
        # count += 1
    elif sum(integers) > number:
        pass
    elif integers_available == []:
        pass
    else:
        for c in count_combinations(number, integers_available[:], integers+[integers_available[0]]):
            combination_set.append(c)
            # count += 1
        for c in count_combinations(number, integers_available[1:], integers):
            combination_set.append(c)
            # count += 1

    return len(combination_set)
    # return combination_set
    # return count

# Testing the code
number = 10
integers_available = [5, 2, 3]
print(count_combinations(number, integers_available, []))
```

I expect the result to be 4 since the list is:

[[5, 5], [5, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3, 3]]

> But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ask.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(count_combinations(number, integers_available, []))
  File "ask.py", line 12, in count_combinations
    for c in count_combinations(number, integers_available[:], integers+[integers_available[0]]):
  File "ask.py", line 12, in count_combinations
    for c in count_combinations(number, integers_available[:], integers+[integers_available[0]]):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `count_combinations` returns an `int`, but you also do `for c in count_combinations(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is recursive.  You can wait to convert the list to a length at the end of the work like:

```
def get_combinations(number, integers_available, integers):

    combination_set = []
    # count = 0

    if sum(integers) == number:
        combination_set.append(integers)
        # count += 1
    elif sum(integers) > number:
        pass
    elif integers_available == []:
        pass
    else:
        for c in get_combinations(number, integers_available[:],
                                  integers + [integers_available[0]]):
            combination_set.append(c)
            # count += 1
        for c in get_combinations(number, integers_available[1:],
                                  integers):
            combination_set.append(c)
            # count += 1

    return combination_set

def count_combinations(number, integers_available, integers):
    return len(get_combinations(number, integers_available, integers))


# Testing the code
number = 10
integers_available = [5, 2, 3]
print(count_combinations(number, integers_available, []))
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot that the function is recursive and keeps calling itself. I'll find a way to bundle this into one function if possible but at least I've seen where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `get_combinations(number, integers_available, integers)` as recursive function so  this function returns `return len(combination_set)` the length  the list `combination_set = []`. when you use this function like

`for c in get_combinations(number, integers_available[:],
                                  integers + [integers_available[0]]):`

since the function returns an integer which is the length of the list, the above for each loop means

```
for c in len(combination_set):
```

Note:
  lets say the length is `4`

```
for c in 4: # throws 'int' object is not iterable exception.
```

So your function should return the list not the length of the list
It should be `return combination_set`

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that number is valid when it is not 0 then You can then try the code below:

```
def get_combinations2(number, integers_available, integers):
     return len(integers_available)+len(integers)+1 if number != 0 else len(integers_available)+len(integers)
```